# With nginx how do I do a mass redirect of all www sites to non www sites

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Something like

```
 server {
   listen 80 default;
   server_name  _ ;
   root /home/drew/sites/$host;
   rewrite ^www(.*) http://$host$1 permanent;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 server {
   listen 80 default;
   server_name the very first;
   rewrite "^www\.(.*)" http://$1 permanent;
 }
```

Then use respective server declarations with their roots

Comment: What does "server the very first" mean?

Comment: It is just important taht this server declaration to be the very first for nginx. Maybe even in nginx.conf or make sites-enabled/000-default. No matter what server name you give to it. Put something nonexistent

Comment: If you mark it as default (or default_server in the stable version which you should be using!) then it doesn't matter where in the config it's located.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to mass redirect www sites to non www

```
 server {
   listen 80 default;
   server_name  _ ;
   if ($host ~ ^(www\.)(?<domain2>.+)$) {
      set $domain2 $2;
      rewrite ^ http://$domain2$request_uri?;
   }
   root /home/drew/sites/$host;
 }
```